# PCRE regex. remove string 1 from the end of string 2, with any number of * chars

Tags: php, regex, pcre

So - I have strings like this (string1 examples):

```
'aaaaabbbbbcccccword'
'aaaaabbbbbcccccwor*d'
'aaaaabbbbbcccccw**ord*'
'aaaaabbbbbccccc*word*'
```

And I need to remove some substring (string2) from the end of those strings along with any * characters in string2 a well as * preceding string2 and following string2. string2 is some variable. I can't think of a regex that can be used here.

```
//wrong example, * that might happen to be inside of $string1 are not removed :(
$string1 = 'aaaaabbbbbcccccw**ord*';
$string2 = 'word';
$result = preg_replace('#\*?' . $string2 . '\*?$#', '', $string1);
```

Can someone suggest a PCRE regex for that?

**P.S. Can I get upvoted to like at list 15 points? SO I can upvote people?**

Comment: Input string don't contain any search string `test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$regexp = '#\**' . implode('\**', str_split($string2)) . '\**$#';
$result = preg_replace($regexp, '', $string1);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/PF8WDz)

`str_split` splits the string up into characters, and then `implode` inserts `\**` between each of them. Then we put `\**` before and after it to grab any surrounding `*` characters as well.

Comment: The two answers differ in how they deal with multiple `*` before/after the word. My answer will remove all of them, @anubhava's answer will only match one optional `*` at each end.

Comment: But your earlier version was using array_map isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but that was overly complicated, so I copied your implode(). The only difference between our solutions now is the surrounding wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing that:

```
$string1 = 'aaaaabbbbbcccccw**ord*';
$string2 = 'word';
$result = preg_replace('#\*?' . implode('\**', str_split($string2)) . '\*?$#', '',
                        $string1);
echo $result;
//=> aaaaabbbbbccccc
```